# Save.json file locally in R

Tags: r, json

I'm generating a `.json` file from a `data.frame`, but I would like to save this generated `.json` file on my computer, that is, locally. How to adjust this?

```
library(jsonlite)

df1 = data.frame(CustomerId = c(1:6), Product = c(rep("Toaster", 3), rep("Radio", 3)))
df1<-toJSON(df1)
```

Comment: use `write_json` i.e. `write_json(df1, "path/to/yourfile.json")`

Comment: Thank you very much! I have a question that is a little similar, for example, if I have a database in Excel, with 4 sheets, then I do the following command: `df1<-read_excel('C:/Users/Livia/Desktop /df1.xlsx')`, but it only reads the first sheet, so when I run your code, it doesn't generate a file. `.json` for all sheets, do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we use `read_excel` and wants to retrieve all the sheets, get the sheets first, then loop over those and specify the sheet name in `sheet`, and them into a `list`

```
library(readxl)
library(purrr)
sheet_nms <- excel_sheets("C:/Users/Livia/Desktop /df1.xlsx")
lst1 <- map(sheet_nms, ~ read_excel("C:/Users/Livia/Desktop /df1.xlsx", 
         sheet = .x))
```

Regarding the original question, we can write with `write_json`

```
library(jsonlite)
write_json(df1, "C:/Users/Livia/Desktop/df1file.json")
```